# Connection of mysql DB with wordpress

Tags: database

i have my food recipe data on mysql database.I use phpmyadmin . Is there any provision to connect to wordpress ? Development of website using wordpress tool ,does  it involve coding or development or its just a tool to be used for static websites ? Does wordpress work for dynamic websites .

Answer (score 0):

1.Wordpress is written in PHP and it's very dynamic.

2.If you use wordpress, you don't need to worry about a database.Wordpress core files will handle that.The database connection infomtion is located in wp-config.php.

3.It really don't require coding when you use worpdress ,there are plenty of handy themes and plugins out there.